# Motion and acceleration in a straight line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A car with an initial velocity of 3 m/s has a velocity of 34 m/s after 3 sec. How far it moves in its third second of motion?

acceleration 
V=U + at
a = 10.3 m/s^2

x = ut + 1/2 a t^2

x = 3 (3) + 1/2 (10.3) (3x3)

x = 56.25 m

but answer in book = 29 m ??

Comment: "in its **third** second", not in three seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like New_new_newbie said, the question asks you to find the distance travelled in its third second (from t=2 to t=3 seconds). So just find x(2) and x(3), and the difference should give you 29m.

Comment: yes, thank you x(2) = 26.67 m, x(3) = 55.5, x(3) - x(2) = 29m